# Is -1 elasticity considered unit elastic or relatively inelastic?

Tags: microeconomics, elasticity

Simple question but can't find answer.

> Is -1 elasticity considered unit elastic or relatively inelastic?

We know that if % change in quantity / % change in price = 1, we have unit elastic, does that hold true for -1 elasticity?

The top google result for unit elastic is

> In economics, unit elastic (also known as unitary elastic) is a term that describes a situation in which a change in one variable results in an equally proportional change in another variable.

which use the terms `proportional`, so is -1 elasticity considered unit elastic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -1 elasticity is unit elastic. Elasticity is also often reported in absolute value so |-1|=1. In fact I am almost certain that  whoever told you that " % change in quantity / % change in price = 1," was talking about absolute value of elasticity because demand is almost always downward sloping with rare exception of Giffen goods.

Also when elasticity is -1 or 1 the change in quantity and price are proportional since that implies 1 percent increase in price leads to 1 percent decrease (increase) in quantity demanded (if we talk about demand elasticity can be computed for other things as well).

Comment: Thanks, that makes most sense. Last question, every time if we use the formula ` % change in quantity / % change in price` to determine elasticity ((like perfectly inelastic, relatively inelastic, unit elastic, perfectly elastic and  relatively elastic)), we are use absolute value, right ? Thanks!

Comment: @James not every time some people just don’t like negative value for elasticity so they will say elasticity is 1 instead of -1 but rigorous work will usually tell leader that’s it’s expressing it in absolute value

Comment: Got it and thanks!:)